# How can I prove this? For every integer m with 2 divides m and 4 does not divide m, there are no integers x and y that satisfy x^2+3y^2=m.

Tags: proof-writing

I know that m is even and m/2 is odd, but I don't know where/how I can use this. Also, 3y^2 is odd and the sum is odd when x^2 is even. I'm trying to prove that its always odd, but I'm stuck.
Can someone please help?
Thanks

Comment: Please don't have part of your question only in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose : $m=x^2+3y^2$ is even.

Case $1$ : $x$ is even. Then $y$ must be even as well. So, $m$ is divisble by $4$.

Case $2$ : $x$ is odd. Then, $\ x^2\equiv 1 \mod 4\ $. Since $y$ must be odd as well, we also have $\ y^2\equiv 1\mod 4\ $. Hence, $x^2+3y^2\equiv 0\mod 4$.

So, again, $m$ is divisble by $4$

Comment: It is given that m is not divisible by 4. The question is asking to prove that the equation x^2 + 3y^2 = m has no solution.

Comment: I have done a contradiction-proof. If $m$ is divisble by $2$ and of the form $x^2+3y^2$, then it must be divisble by $4$. Hence, if $n$ is divisble by $2$, but not by $4$, it cannot be of the form $x^2+3y^2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\,\ 2\!:\ x\equiv y\ \Rightarrow\ {\rm mod}\,\ 4\!:\ x^2\equiv y^2\equiv -3y^2$